# Ajax pagination with class based view

Tags: python-3.x, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying apply ajax with pagination on my app .Using Class based Listview

```
#views.py
class HomePage(ListView):
model = Video
template_name = 'index.html'


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(HomePage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    videos = Video.objects.filter(category='sub')
    paginator = Paginator(videos, 5)
    page = self.request.GET.get('page2')
    try:
        videos = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        videos = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        videos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context['videos'] = videos

    if self.request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('videos/index.html', context, request=self.request)
        print(html)
    return JsonResponse({'form' : html })
```

The Home template script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function(event){
                            $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(event){
                                event.preventDefault();
                                var page = $(this).attr('href');
                                console.log(page)
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'GET',
                                    url: ,
                                    data: {'page':'{{ page.number }}'},
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success: function(response){
                                        $('#ajax_page_template').html(response['form'])
                                        console.log("success")
                                       
                                    },
                                    error: function(rs, e){
                                        console.log(rs.responseText);
                                    },
                                });
                            });
                        });

                    </script>
```

1.The current error is in views.py `local variable 'html' referenced before assignment`

2.And what should I put in ajax --url: I tried to put url:page but that return url to `127.0.0.1:8000/?page=2/?page=2.`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and got it working:

In views.py add "paginate_by = 4" and def get_template_names:

```
class HomePage(ListView):
    ...
    paginate_by = 4

def get_template_names(self):
    template_name = 'list.html'
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        template_name = 'list_ajax.html'
    return template_name
```

Use 2 templates:

New list_ajax.html with the for loop:

```
{% for video in video_list %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Existing template list.html:

```
<div id="image-list">
  {% include 'list_ajax.html' %}
</div>
```

In the script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2.2.1/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
  function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
  }
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var page = 1;
    var empty_page = false;
    var block_request = false;
    var num_pages=parseInt('{{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}')
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var margin = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200;
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() > margin && empty_page == false &&
        block_request == false) {
        block_request = true;
        page += 1;
        if(num_pages-page >= 0) {
        $.get('?page=' + page, function(data) {
            block_request = false;
            console.log(data)
            $('#image-list').append(data);
            }
        );
        }}
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the `html` variable before you use it. Like this:

```
 html = ""
 if self.request.is_ajax():
     html = render_to_string('videos/index.html', context, request=self.request)
```

And the `url` you should put in the ajax call is the one corresponding to the relevant view (`HomePage`).

And change the following line:

```
return JsonResponse({'form' : html })
```

To:

```
render(request,'videos/index.html',JsonResponse(html))
```

Comment: it's showing TypeError at /

context must be a dict rather than JsonResponse

Comment: TypeError at /

In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.

Comment: I don't understand why we have to change views--  html = " " .in this while in my other app which have function based view everything works fine ,Is it happening because of class based view?